# How to Fire FormFlow from LuisIntent in BotFramework

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm working with Microsoft's BotFramework in C#. I have a LUIS Intent, and from there I want to fire a FormFlow, but I honestly don't know how to do it.

```
[LuisModel("35554cdf-92ae-4413-*", "*")]
[Serializable]
public class LuisIntegration : LuisDialog<Object>
{
    public BuildFormDelegate<Cotizacion> _configurecotizacion;
    public BuildFormDelegate<Cotizacion> LuisDialog(BuildFormDelegate<Cotizacion> configureCotizacion) => _configurecotizacion = configureCotizacion;

    [LuisIntent("Cotizar")]
    public async Task CotizarAsync(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        var entitiesArray = result.Entities;

        var form = new FormDialog<Cotizacion>(new Cotizacion(), Cotizacion.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart, result.Entities);

        context.Call(new FormDialog<Cotizacion>(new Cotizacion(), this._configurecotizacion, FormOptions.PromptInStart), ResumeAfterCallback);
    }

    private async Task ResumeAfterCallback(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<Cotizacion> result)
    {
        Cotizacion coti = null;

        try
        {
            coti = await result;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Cancelaste la cotización.");
            return;
        }

        //context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }
}


public static IForm<Cotizacion> BuildForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<Cotizacion>()
                .Message("¡Listo! Necesito algunos datos para cotizar, empecemos.")
                .Field(nameof(Nombre))
                .Field(nameof(Apellido))
                .Field(nameof(Provincia))
                .Field(nameof(Localidad))
                .Field(nameof(Edad))
                .Field(new FieldReflector<Cotizacion>(nameof(Marca))
                    .SetType(null)
                    .SetDefine(async (state, field) =>
                    {
                        foreach (var prod in await Gets.ObtenerMarcasAsync())
                            field
                                .AddDescription(prod, prod)
                                .AddTerms(prod, prod);

                        return await Task.FromResult(true);
                    }))
                .Field(new FieldReflector<Cotizacion>(nameof(Modelo))
                    .SetType(null)
                    .SetDefine(async (state, field) =>
                    {
                        foreach (var prod in await Gets.ObtenerModelosAsync(state.Marca))
                            field
                                .AddDescription(prod, prod)
                                .AddTerms(prod, prod);

                        return await Task.FromResult(true);
                    }))
                .Field(nameof(Anio))
                .Field(nameof(Version))
                .Field(nameof(Email))
                .Field(nameof(Telefono))
                .Field(nameof(Sexo))
                .Confirm("Estamos a punto de cotizar tu auto, ¿está correcta la información que ingresaste?")
                .OnCompletion(async (context, state) => { ... }
```

The FormFlow alone works perfectly, the problem is when I added the LuisIntent.

I fixed the problem calling the FormFlow, the problem now is that is not prompting the confirm, therefore is not finishing. It hangs in the last property of the form. I updated the code.

Edit 2:

```
private async Task ResumeAfterCallback(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<Cotizacion> result)
    {
        Cotizacion coti = null;

        try
        {
            coti = await result;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Cancelaste la cotización.");
            return;
        }

        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }
```

Edit 3:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new LuisIntegration());
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: What issue are you having with the current code? It looks good to me.

Comment: @EzequielJadib, thanks for the response. I updated the code, my problem change a little bit. When I say 'cotizar' to the bot, it calls the FormFlow, but when is complete, it is not prompting the Confirm, and the OnCompletion method is not fired either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: the (final) issue is in the definition of the `DefineAsyncDelegate` parameter to FieldReflector's `SetDefine` method:

```
public delegate Task<bool> DefineAsyncDelegate<T>(T state, Field<T> field) where T : class;
```

It is not explicitly required to be an `async` method, but since the implementation above uses async calls within it ('Gets.ObtenerXXXAsync()'), the method should return a bool and not a wrapped `Task.FromResult<bool>`.

If the `async` was omitted, and the Gets.ObtenerXXXAsync() was called using a Task.Run(...).Result, for example, then it would be correct to return a Task.FromResult(true).

....

Maybe your bot is obsessed with 'Sexo'... :)

Why do you need your `BuildFormDelegate<Cotizacion>` member variables? Your `CotizarAsync` method could just look like this:

```
    [LuisIntent("Cotizar")]
    public async Task CotizarAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
    {
        context.Call(new FormDialog<Cotizacion>(new Cotizacion(), Cotizacion.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart, result.Entities), 
            ResumeAfterCallback);
    }
```

which just passes `Cotizacion.BuildForm` to the FormDialog constructor.

I tried a cut-down version in my LUIS bot (with just `Nombre` and `Apellido` in `Cotizacion`) and it worked OK - the `ResumeAfterCallback` was called successfully.

Comment: Hey! I tried this, and now when I say 'cotizar', it jump to the catch of the ResumeAfterCallback. I updated the post with that method.

Comment: Bizarre. Have you tried cutting down your Cotizacion object to just one or two fields (and removing the body of the OnCompletionAsyncDelegate) just to be sure?

Comment: Out of interest, how is your MessagesController's Post method invoking your 'LuisIntegration' dialog?

Comment: that was really helpful! So I cuted down the Cotizacion.BuildForm until it worked. The problem is in `.Field(new FieldReflector<Cotizacion>(nameof(Marca))` and the other one wich is similar. That two should retrive a list of strings from a `public static async Task<List<string>>`. Why that is causing this?

Comment: You don't need `return await Task.FromResult(true);`; `return true;` will do fine, although that's probably not your main problem.

Again, I tried a simple version with a FieldReflector and it worked OK. Your issue is most likely an async problem - something is probably not being `await`ed properly? I would suggest you try again with just `string Marca` added to your model, and replace the body of `Gets.ObtenerMarcasAsync()` with something simple like `return new List<string>() { "a", "b" "c" };`. Then, if that works, work up from there.

Comment: Well, the problem was in fact the return await Task.FromResult(true). I changed to return true and it works! Please change your answer and I will mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Done. Glad it's all sorted.